# Convert String into Expression SQL for each Row

Tags: sql, math

Hello I Searched a lot for this and I couldnt find a good solution for this.

Lets imagine a have a following query

```
Select width, height, depth, formula from myTable
```

I want to do a replace in the formula to convert 
w into width values
h into height values
d into depth values

and then I want to convert this result string ex:
'(1+2)*3' into a expression, so it gets calculated.

I came across some answers using

```
exec ('select '+@expression)
```

But that does not work for each row. I simply cant use a exec inside a select. 
Like this

```
select 1 as col1, exec ('select '+@expression) as col2
```

Or even convert string into expression
something like

```
Cast('1+1' as expression)
```

The final result that i need is simple. follows bellow.

```
+-------+--------+-------+---------+--------+
| width | height | depth | formula | result |
+-------+--------+-------+---------+--------+
| 1     | 2      | 3     | (w+h)*d | 12     |
+-------+--------+-------+---------+--------+
| 2     | 1      | 3     | d+d*h   | 6      |
+-------+--------+-------+---------+--------+
| 3     | 3      | 1     | (d/4)*d | 0.25   |
+-------+--------+-------+---------+--------+
```

Comment: So there are many formula types in your table?much more than 3 types?Or only 3 types?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, your best best is building a user defined function that parses that accepts the width, height, depth and formula, parses the formula into an arithmetic calculation and returns the result. HOWEVER, I really don't know if this is worth the effort. Maybe take a look at your wider system. Can this not be calculated somewhere other than the DB?

Comment: @Shawn.X The end user can change the formula at will directly in an aplication, I want to be able to do the calculation directly in SQL, they can create the formula as they wish.

Comment: @BarryPiccinni I'm using SQL SERVER 2016

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in a simple query, because the formula changes on each row.  One method to get the results is to iterate through the table and execute each row separately.  Something like this:

declare @sql nvarchar(max);

declare @id int = 0;
declare @maxid int;

select @maxid = max(id) from mytable;

```
while @id < @maxid
begin
    select @sql = concat('select ', width, ' as width, ', height, ' as height, ', depth, ' as depth, ', formula, ' as value, ''', formula + ''' as formula',
                  ' from (select ', width, ' as w, ', height, ' as h, ', depth, 'as d) x')
    from mytable t
    order by id
    offset @id rows fetch next 1 row only;

    exec sp_executesql @sql;

    set @id = @id + 1;
end;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=40b46b6b8c3514ef62f5041e66fee7bb) is a db<>fiddle.